# Codeigniter giving unusual results on login controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter framework. I have a login model and a controller with a view. I have admin as username and admin as password set in the users table in my db for test purpose.
But when ever I use admin13356 or admindsgsd or adminWHATEVER with admin as password, the login is successful. I dont understand why.

My controller function is as follows.

```
function check(){
        $this->load->model('loginModel');
        $query = $this->loginModel->validate();
        if($query){
            $data = array('username' => $this->input->post('username'),
                           'is_logged_in' => true
                        );
            $this->session->set_userdata($data);
            //redirecting to appropriate page 
            redirect('success');
        }else{
            $this->session->set_flashdata('loginCheck','Username/Password Comination Incorrect!');
            redirect('login');
        }
    }
```

And my model is as below.

```
function validate(){
            $this->db->where('username', $this->input->post('username'));
            $this->db->where('password', md5($this->input->post('password')));
            $query = $this->db->get('users');
            if($query->num_rows() == 1){
                return true;
            }

        }
```

Comment: The code looks fine, but I would remove the post data variables from the model, and instead create variables in the controller and pass them along as paramaters of your `validate()` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version of PHP are you running? I've had problems with PHP before where it returns TRUE for non returns.

Try adding `return false` to your validate() method:

```
function validate(){
    $this->db->where('username', $this->input->post('username'));
    $this->db->where('password', md5($this->input->post('password')));
    $query = $this->db->get('users');
    if($query->num_rows() == 1){
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Also, Model's should be input agnostic. Definitely think about moving the `$this->input->post()` to the controller and pass the values in as parameters:

This allows you to use the `validate()` method in other scenarios. For example (re-validating the password when the username isn't supplied via post but via session).

**Controller**

```
function check(){
    $this->load->model('loginModel');
    $query = $this->loginModel->validate($this->input->post('username'), $this->input->post('password'));
    if($query){
        $data = array(
           'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
           'is_logged_in' => true
        );
        $this->session->set_userdata($data);
        //redirecting to appropriate page 
        redirect('success');
    }else{
        $this->session->set_flashdata('loginCheck', 'Username/Password Combination Incorrect!');
        redirect('login');
    }
}
```

**Model**

```
function validate($username, $password){
    $this->db->where('username', $username);
    $this->db->where('password', md5($password));
    $query = $this->db->get('users');
    if($query->num_rows() == 1){
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function validate(){
           // dump all post variables recieved
           echo '<pre>';
           print_r($this->input->post());                
           echo '</pre><br>';    

            $this->db->where('username', $this->input->post('username'));
            $this->db->where('password', md5($this->input->post('password')));
            $query = $this->db->get('users');

           // Dump what the query result is
           echo '<br><pre>';
           print_r($query->result());                
           echo '</pre>';

            //if($query->num_rows() == 1){
            //    return true;
            //}

        }
```

Your code seems fine, but can you check if it is passing the right data correctly try dumping it first. like the code above to check the data and the query result.

Answer (score 1):

how many records do you have in the **table**

try this code

```
function validate($username,$password){
            $this->select('*');
            $this->from('table_name');
            $this->db->where('username', $username);
            $this->db->where('password', md5($password));
            $query = $this->db->get();
            if($query->num_rows() == 1){
                return true;
            }

        }
```

pass your `username` and `password` to the function